# Can glycerin crack a glass when heated?

Tags: safety

Is it safe to put glycerin in double wall glass candle ( between the walls ) for decor purposes. I know they put it in vapes and double glass wall coffee tumblers. Is there a possibility of it to crack the either inner wall( the one that will be heated by the wax first ) or outside one if heated by candle burning? In condition if chamber with glycerin is closed .Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

Not chemically, but from usual, thermal or mechanical reasons.

Direct flame contact or frequent or regular thermal shocks can crack glass. Heating resistant glass significantly decreases the risk, but does not eliminate it. The prolonged history of heating, together with tiny surface damages, increases the risk.

Heated liquids can crack glass, if kept in closed container. Either directly by thermal dilation, either indirectly by vapour pressure. Minor water content can cause significant pressure if heated enough.